# :source $MYVIMRC doesnt work to my original buffer

Tags: vim

i have this mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
:map <leader>e :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:map <leader>ee :tabedit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:map <leader>s :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

i can edit in new tab or split (so now i have 2 buffers - `.vimrc` and the original) but when i make some changes to my `.vimrc`, and the get beck to original buffer (by `<c-w>l`), and press `<leader>s`, it shows me at the command line `:source $MYVIMRC<cr>` but actually doesnt do anything. I tried it many times , just by adding mapping like `:nnoremap stuff istuff` - to write stuff, and the `<leader>s` in my original buffer, but nothing happened. It is really strange, since it works in my `.vimrc` buffer (when i source my new changes in own `.vimrc` buffer) but not in my original (as i get back to it), so is there any special sourcing to other buffers, or when does the sourcing should happen, everytime i press `<leader>s`? I really dont get it.

EDIT:

just realize it is even stranger. When i add some new mapping, and then source in new buffer... it works. BUT when i delete them from `.vimrc`, and source again... IT STILL WORKS despite it is no longer it `.vimrc`... this is really weird.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: Re: edit—if you setup a mapping, it persists until you unmap. Just bc its not in your vimrc doesnt mean it gets unmapped. When you quit vim, mappings go away, and then when you open it again, your vimrc is run and only mappings created there are available. But thats not the same as simply sourcing your vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what is going on from your description of the problem...

But one possible explanation (and definitely something you should fix) is that you're using `:map` instead of ,`:nnoremap` in your `<leader>s` mapping.

When you use `:map`, the expansion will be recursively checked for other mappings, which is most likely not really what you want, in most cases, and particularly in this one. It can also end up having different behavior per buffer, since it's possible you will trigger a recursive mapping that only exists on that buffer (for instance, `FileType`-specific mappings.)

In this specific case, I think only a mapping for `:` would affect this (since then you go into Ex mode and mappings are less of an issue), and I don't really think `:` is mapped often or would map to something that produces the side effects you describe... But still that's definitely something to fix. So update your mappings to:

```
:nnoremap <leader>e :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>ee :tabedit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>s :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

Another thing is the side-effect you described, of typing the command with a literal `<cr>` and leaving it there for you to press enter. This could be explained if your [`'cpoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27) includes [`<`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-%3C), which is the case when [`'compatible'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) is set (or, in other words, before `'nocompatible'` is set.)

It's possible that what you're actually seeing doesn't depend on the buffers where the command is executed, but that the first time `.vimrc` is sourced, at startup, these mappings are being configured while `compatible` is set, and so end up with the `<cr>` that doesn't work as an "Enter", but instead gets inserted literally. Once you source your `.vimrc` once again, after `'nocompatible'` was set, then the mappings are configured again, but this time with the proper meaning of `<cr>` and, from then on, the mappings work correctly, as you expect.

So I'd recommend adding an explicit setting to the top of your `.vimrc`, that might be enough to solve this issue. Add this line:

```
set nocompatible
```

Comment: You dont usually need set nocompatible with vim (its done automatically if a vimrc is found).

Comment: @DBenKnoble Agreed. But I believe this might somewhat depend on the version of Vim and the timing of it is unclear to me. I've still seen `set nocompatible` in the first few lines of `.vimrc` (possibly a lot due to cargo culting) but I thought it was worth suggesting it as something easy to try and also easy to rule out if that's not really the root of the issue.

Comment: Fair enough. I think mine has the equivalent of `if &compatible | set nocompatible | endif` at the top

Comment: @DBenKnoble Yes, I think even `defaults.vim` ships with that comment at the top and a comment explaining it...